# Retrieving a parent tag with a given attribute that contains a subelement by using XPath

Tags: xpath

How I can retrieve multiple DIVs (with a given class attribute "a") that contain a span tag with a class attribute "b" by using Xpath?

```
<div class='a'>
<span class='b'/>
</div>
```

The structure of my XML is not defined so basically the span could be at any level of the div and the div itself could be at any level of the XML tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
//div[@class='a'][span/@class='b']
```

`//` means *search anywhere* if it starts the expression.

If the `span` is deeper in the `div`, use `descendant::` which can be shortened to `//` again:

```
//div[@class='a'][.//span/@class='b']
```

Comment: Works for me in http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath. Check the update, too - I noticed you can have the `span` nested deeper.

Comment: Yes, the second one you suggested is working. Thanks